# React Testing, how to mock graphql and throw exception

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, graphql

Somtimes I have code like this

```
updateProfileMutate(...)
      .then().catch(e => {console.error(e);}
```

or

```
try{
 apolloClient.mutate(...);
}catch(e){
   console.error(e);
}
```

How to mock the query and throw an exception? There is something I want to assert inside the catch block.

Comment: You can simulate errors with apollo client like explained here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-error-states

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JohannesKlauß, apollo error will be captured in error objects, its throwing though, so catch block testing can be covered